# How can I update a cell to today's date if something changes in a different cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am setting a tool for users to enter evidence to verify that a task has been completed. When they enter this evidence it's important that the column with "date completed" be updated to show today's date. I have looked in a variety of places for help with this, but I can't find anything that does this.

I included an example screenshot of what I want to happen... When something changes in the evidence column, I want the date to be updated in the row where the changes occurred. [image]

Comment: You use the `Worksheet_Change()` event: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

Comment: That approach is demonstrated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1151359/excel-vba-timestamp-in-predefined-row-when-data-is-changed-in-a-column).

Comment: Is there a way to automatically implement this method rather than as a sub?

Comment: No. There is no automated way since it has to be triggered by a change only.

Comment: @N.Whyter what exactly do you mean by "automatically implement"? I.e. do you want the date entered "automatically" whenever evidence is entered, as opposed to a step in a sub that  is run "on-demand"? If the former, `Worksheet_Change()` is the way to go, as @JNevill points out.

Comment: I want it to recognize that the cell in the same row with the evidence information has been changed and alter the date accordingly. The links may give me the answer, but I'm still trying to figure out how to make this happen. Especially since my range isn't a specific set of cells. My range is a cell dependent upon the row. It seems like I might be able to do this with a UDF, but not sure...

Comment: `Worksheet_Change()` is your friend. Your range is a "cell dependent upon the row" - you can get that row from `Target`. See the links for more. If you get stuck, feel free to edit your question with the code you have.

Comment: Looks like that is putting me on the right track. From what I've seen it doesn't detect changes in cell interior fill color. Any way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming the value to be changed is in Col A and your dates will go in column immediately to the right of your value change. If these assumptions are not true, and you need help modifying, please let me know.

Note that this will only be activated when a cell is physically changed.
(Formulas / conditional formats will not trigger a worksheet change)

Paste the below code in the sheet where you want it to run

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim LRow As Long
LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("A2:A" & LRow)

If Not Intersect(target, MyRange) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Now()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The current time stamp will show date AND time. You can easily figure out how to swap this for a date without time (or just format this column in excel to taste).